# Using JSDoc in Netbeans for code completion on objects

Tags: netbeans, documentation, jsdoc

I'm trying to get Netbeans to provide some code completion on objects. Here is the basic code without JSdoc:

```
; var docTest = ( function( $, MyGlobal ){
  console.log( MyGlobal.foo );
} )( jQuery, SOME_GLOBAL_OBJECT );
```

`SOME_GLOBAL_OBJECT` is defined elsewhere and is basically a configuration object that looks something like this:

```
var SOME_GLOBAL_OBJECT = { foo: "bar", baz: "blech" };
```

I'm hoping it's possible to coerce Netbeans to auto-suggest "foo" and "baz" when I type `MyGlobal.`

I've tried a few things, such as:

```
/**
* @typedef Global - My global options
* @type {object}
* @property {string} foo - Some foo
* @property {string} baz - Blech!
/*
```

Followed by

```
/**
* @param {jQuery} $
* @param {Global} MyGlobal
*/
function ( $, MyGlobal ){ // ....
```

And I've also tried

```
/**
* @param {jQuery} $
* @param {{ foo: string, baz: string }} MyGlobal
*/

function ( $, MyGlobal ){ //....
```

And even

```
/** @type {{ foo: string, baz: string }} MyGlobal */
```

But no joy. Is this sort of thing supported in Netbeans 7.4? What's the correct way to document my object so that Netbeans knows about its properties?